# Missing request token for request

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, request, multipartform-data

Get all contacts from phonebook and upload to server but got following error.

While append image in request body `FormData`

[image]

**Tried code**

pass file url contact thumbnailPath

```
const path = con.thumbnailPath
body.append('image', {
     uri: path,
     type: 'image/jpeg',
     name: 'photo.jpg',
     type: 'multipart/form-data'
})
```

**Tried code**

pass file url contact thumbnailPath without "file://"

```
const path = con.thumbnailPath.replace('file://', '')
body.append('image', {
     uri: path,
     type: 'image/jpeg',
     name: 'photo.jpg',
     type: 'multipart/form-data'
})
```

**Tried code**

check file exist on path or not with using `react-native-fs`

```
if (con.thumbnailPath != '') {
     let isExist = RNFS.exists(con.thumbnailPath)
     if (isExist) {
         const path = con.thumbnailPath.replace('file://', '')
         console.log("Exist", path)
         body.append('image', {
             uri: path,
             type: 'image/jpeg',
             name: 'photo.jpg',
             type: 'multipart/form-data'
         })
     }
}
```

**Request**

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': token,
        'token': token
    },
    body: params 
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((json) => {
    console.log("RESPONSE:- ", json)
    if (json.response[0].status == 'false') {
        let msg = json.response[0].response_msg
        callback(new Error(msg), json.response[0])
    }
    else {
        callback(null, json.response[0])
    }
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    callback(err, null)
})
```

Comment: It seems like your request token is missing from header. Please ensure API Work correctly in postman or other tools

Comment: it is not an api error @HiteshSurani 
Crashing issue while append image into body

Comment: Please refer this(https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10553) may be help you.

Comment: Thanks @HiteshSurani 
I have already checked that solution but it is not working for me

Comment: Please add `fetch` code in your question.

Comment: Please check @StanislavMayorov

Comment: If you're using oauth2 then `fetch` `headers` should look like `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token`, and no direct `token` header.

Comment: There is an no issue with fetch request. error occurs while append image into request body. some images are not working @Alex

Comment: How about using FormData
https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-upload-images-in-a-react-native-app-4cca03ded855
https://github.com/g6ling/React-Native-Tips/tree/master/How_to_upload_photo%2Cfile_in%20react-native

Comment: Question: why does your sample code show JPEG this, JPEG that, but the actual error in question point to a PNG file? maybe *that's* the problem?

Comment: Have the same issue. @HarshalValanda how did you solve that?

Comment: Im having the same issue too. How did you solve it? @HarshalValanda

Comment: @RenielRamosSalvador change native module `RCTNetwork.m`

Comment: @HarshalValanda How did you change the native module?

Comment: @StephenA.Lizcano search Missing request token for request Network.m file and commit code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issues comes from `react-native@0.63.2`'s internal bug.

A quick solution is to revert this commit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/31980094107ed37f8de70972dbcc319cc9a26339#diff-9a034658197479288c4d346a0eb4d98c

After manually revert this commit in `node_modules`, recompile the app and the image uploading will be working without any issues.

Replace the function `loadImageForURL` in  `/Libraries/Image/RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.mm` with the following:

```
 - (RCTImageLoaderCancellationBlock)loadImageForURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
                                           size:(CGSize)size
                                          scale:(CGFloat)scale
                                     resizeMode:(RCTResizeMode)resizeMode
                                progressHandler:(RCTImageLoaderProgressBlock)progressHandler
                             partialLoadHandler:(RCTImageLoaderPartialLoadBlock)partialLoadHandler
                              completionHandler:(RCTImageLoaderCompletionBlock)completionHandler
 {
   __block auto cancelled = std::make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(false);
   RCTExecuteOnMainQueue(^{
     if (cancelled->load()) {
       return;
     }

     UIImage *image = RCTImageFromLocalAssetURL(imageURL);
     if (image) {
       if (progressHandler) {
         progressHandler(1, 1);
       }
       completionHandler(nil, image);
     } else {
       NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not find image %@", imageURL];
       RCTLogWarn(@"%@", message);
       completionHandler(RCTErrorWithMessage(message), nil);
     }
   });

   return ^{
     cancelled->store(true);
   };
 }
```

Comment: Nice tip, but what could be the solution without downgrading the whole react? 
"react-native": "github:facebook/react-native#31980094107ed37f8de70972dbcc319cc9a26339" ?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package to apply the patch easily

Answer (score 5):

This problem is fixed in 0.63.3 ✅

Answer (score 3):

```
**For IOS** in 
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.mm   file

**Replace Below** 

 - -(RCTImageLoaderCancellationBlock)loadImageForURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
                                               size:(CGSize)size
                                              scale:(CGFloat)scale
                                         resizeMode:(RCTResizeMode)resizeMode
                                    progressHandler:(RCTImageLoaderProgressBlock)progressHandler
                                 partialLoadHandler:(RCTImageLoaderPartialLoadBlock)partialLoadHandler
                                  completionHandler:(RCTImageLoaderCompletionBlock)completionHandler
{
  UIImage *image = RCTImageFromLocalAssetURL(imageURL);
  if (image) {
    if (progressHandler) {
      progressHandler(1, 1);
    }
    completionHandler(nil, image);
  } else {
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not find image %@", imageURL];
    RCTLogWarn(@"%@", message);
    completionHandler(RCTErrorWithMessage(message), nil);
  }
  
  return nil;
}

**With**



 - -(RCTImageLoaderCancellationBlock)loadImageForURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
                                           size:(CGSize)size
                                          scale:(CGFloat)scale
                                     resizeMode:(RCTResizeMode)resizeMode
                                progressHandler:(RCTImageLoaderProgressBlock)progressHandler
                             partialLoadHandler:(RCTImageLoaderPartialLoadBlock)partialLoadHandler
                              completionHandler:(RCTImageLoaderCompletionBlock)completionHandler
 {
   __block auto cancelled = std::make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(false);
   RCTExecuteOnMainQueue(^{
     if (cancelled->load()) {
       return;
     }

     UIImage *image = RCTImageFromLocalAssetURL(imageURL);
     if (image) {
       if (progressHandler) {
         progressHandler(1, 1);
       }
       completionHandler(nil, image);
     } else {
       NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not find image %@", imageURL];
       RCTLogWarn(@"%@", message);
       completionHandler(RCTErrorWithMessage(message), nil);
     }
   });

   return ^{
     cancelled->store(true);
   };
 }

This..

Like and Love , if it work
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue which perfectly reproducible on one of the iPhone 7 on my react-native project. It's strange but another iPhone 7's works perfectly as well as all Android devices.

**My code:**

```
formdata.append("file", {uri: photo.uri, name: name_img, type: 'image/jpeg' });

axios({
   url: `${API}${'/upload'}`,
   method: 'post',
   headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth_token,
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   data: formdata
}).then(response => this.saveRoute())
  .catch(err => {         
     this.props.errorMessage({message: err})
  }
})
```

**Few things that I investigate:**

- I was not able to catch it in debug mode (seams smth wrong in async calls?)
- I was not able to catch it with `try-catch` statement but seams it happened in Axios call.

So, I tried to play with Timeout and was able to make it totally unreproducible with **300ms timeout before Axios call**.

```
formdata.append("file", {uri: photo.uri, name: name_img, type: 'image/jpeg' });
    setTimeout(() =>
      axios({
        url: `${API}${'/upload'}`,
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth_token,
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
    data: formdata
  }).then(response => this.saveRoute())
    .catch(err => {
        this.props.errorMessage({message: err})
      }
    })
  , 300);
```

I know that it's a workaround but may help others to understand the issue for more deep research.

Answer (score 1):

I temporary fixed using `rn-fetch-blob`, but the issue is present in 0.63.2 version and I didn't want to patch node_modules react-native images library.

Answer (score 0):

To send file, you have to create a FormData and append your file into it. See EX: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_a_file

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Just put delay when you post request.

```
let options = {}

options.headers = headers
options.method = 'POST'

let url = {SERVER_URL}

options.body = new FormData();
for (let key in data) {
   options.body.append(key, data[key]);
}
setTimeout(() => {
  fetch(url, options)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
         resolve(responseJson);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         let errParam = {}
         errParam.errMsg = error.toString()
         console.log(errParam)
         resolve(errParam);
    })
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error fixed when updating React Native to version 0.63.3