# React native version 63 image uploading issue

Tags: ios, react-native, file-upload

[image]    Missing request token for request: <NSURLRequest: 0x282528c80> { URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0EFA47FC-4E6B-45B2-98CF-8F43676E6AB4/Documents/signature.png }[image]

**Screenshot attached**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing request token for request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663887/missing-request-token-for-request)

Answer (score 0):

**Replace "file://" to "/private"**

dataForm.append('file', { uri: Platform.OS=='ios'?photo.uri.replace("file://", "/private"):photo.uri, name: 'photo.jpg', type: 'image/jpg' });

IOS : photo.uri.replace("file://", "/private")

It only works for the real device, on simulator still give the error but at least you can deploy your app until this issue is patched